# GHDL, Precompile Vendor Primitives and Cocotb

Tags: ghdl, lattice-diamond, cocotb

I have a design where I use an IP module generated by Lattice Diamond. This uses the Macxo3l library which is shipped with diamond as a vendor library.

Using GHDL I can compile the design including this library using the instructions from https://ghdl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/building/PrecompileVendorPrimitives.html then the commands.

```
ghdl -i --ieee=synopsys -P=lattice/ --workdir=work cores/*.vhd
ghdl -i --workdir=work src/*.vhd
```

However I have been unable to make this compile using cocotb. Below is my make file. Where I use the command VHDL_SOURCES_Lib which I found reference to at https://cocotb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/building.html

```
TOPLEVEL_LANG ?= vhdl

PWD=$(shell pwd)

ifeq ($(OS),Msys)
WPWD=$(shell sh -c 'pwd -W')
PYTHONPATH := $(WPWD)/../model;$(PYTHONPATH)
else
WPWD=$(shell pwd)
PYTHONPATH := $(WPWD)/../model:$(PYTHONPATH)
endif

VHDL_SOURCES_Lib = $(WPWD)/../lattice/
VHDL_SOURCES = $(WPWD)/../cores/Adder.vhd $(WPWD)/../cores/Counter.vhd $(WPWD)/../cores/Multiplyer.vhd $(WPWD)/../cores/SinCos.vhd  $(WPWD)/../src/top.vhd



TOPLEVEL := top
MODULE   := test_of_top

include $(shell cocotb-config --makefiles)/Makefile.inc
include $(shell cocotb-config --makefiles)/Makefile.sim
```

Compiling this however gives me the error:

```
make results.xml
make[1]: Entering directory '/HDL/cocotbTest'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '/HDL/cocotbTest/../cores/Adder.vhd', needed by 'analyse'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/HDL/cocotbTest'
/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cocotb/share/makefiles/Makefile.sim:84: recipe for target 'sim' failed
make: *** [sim] Error 2
```

I am able to run the cocotb examples using GHDL. How should I instruct cocotb to include the Vendor Primitive files.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add the exact filenames in VHDL_SOURCES_Lib as documentation said  :

> VHDL_SOURCES_lib
>
> A **list of the VHDL source files** to include in the VHDL library lib (currently GHDL only).

But to add precompiled library as you show, you have to pass a compile option to ghdl :  -P=lattice/

Use COMPILE_ARGS to add it:

```
COMPILE_ARGS=-P=lattice/
```

Comment: Thanks, Adding the COMPILE_ARGS option as ''COMPILE_ARGS=--ieee=synopsys -P=$(WPWD)/../lattice/''' helped. It now appears to compile the files as it prints a lot of debug to this effect but then appears to recompile them and failed. With the same error as before. I will have another play and see it I can progress a bit further.